# Prove $0 \le e^{-\theta x^2} \le 1$ for $0 \le \theta \le 1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Why is it that $$0 \le e^{-\theta x^2} \le 1$$ for $0 \le \theta \le 1$?

My textbook told me this in the context of langrange remainder for taylor series, and I can't figure it out. (Also, I don't get my head around remainders, for the moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because raising $e$ to a negative power always produces a number smaller than $1.$

Comment: I was so lazy I did not even think about the graph of $e^{-x}$. oh my.

Answer (score 2):

When $1\ge\theta\ge 0$ then since $x^2\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, then $$0\le \theta x^2\le x^2$$ and so $$-x^2\le-\theta x^2\le 0$$ Note that $\exp(x)$ is a increasing function on $\mathbb R$.